# javascript split string like object/array to nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a string like object/array nodes. need to convert string to nodes, using regular expression

```js
const variableName = "parent1[0].child[2].grandChild['name'].deep_child"; // should be n number of child`

// expected result:
const array = ['parent1',0,'child',2,'grandChild','name','deepChild'];
// Note: array's strings property should be any valid variable name like 'parenet' or 'parent1' or 'PARENT' or '_parent_' or 'deep_child'
```

Note

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the desired result by using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
[^\w]
```

[image]

after splitting you may get empty strings so you can use a filter to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out them. At last convert the required number that are in `string` to type `number`

```js
const variableName = "parent1[0].child[2].grandChild['name'].deep_child";

const result = variableName
  .split(/[^\w]/)
  .filter(_ => _)
  .map(a => (isNaN(parseInt(a)) ? a : parseInt(a)));
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with regex `/[\[\].']+/g`.

[Regex Evaluator](https://regexr.com/).

[image]

This regex catches the group between `[` and `].` and splits the string there. Also if ant node of the generated array is a number, convert that to a number using a `map` function.

```js
const variableName = "parent1[0].child[2].grandChild['name'].deep_child";
const output = variableName
            .split(/[\[\].']+/g)
            .map((node) => isNaN(node) ? node : Number(node));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It is not completely correct OP wants `0` or `2` as a `number` not `string`

Comment: Take +1 to 10k. Congo. It feels phenomenal when we see `10k`. Right

Comment: Regex visualizer make it better to understand.

Comment: @decpk how did you generated that image?

Comment: @decpk Thats awesome

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a split of multiple conditions. A simple and good aproach is to replace all of them except one and finally make the split:

```js
// should be n number of child`
const variableName = "parent1[0].child[2].grandChild['name'].deep_child";

const array = variableName
  .replaceAll("'", "")
  .replaceAll("].", "[")
  .split("[")
  .map((x) => (isNaN(x) ? x : +x));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: It is not completely correct OP wants `0` or `2` as a `number` not `string`

Comment: It would be easy for everyone to understand it better if you make your code runnable. :)